# How to write raw SQL queries without hardcoding database names for the Django ORM models and fields?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

I need to use some raw SQL queries in my Django application, but I need to do it in a way that will still work even if the database table and field names change. For example, in one version the query might look like:

```sql
INSERT INTO app_foo_a27e2da2
SELECT DISTINCT
    app_bar_id_309f86af AS app_foo_id_655d53fe,
    app_bar_name_729cb7a0 AS app_foo_name_ad439fec
FROM app_bar_c7c976e7
WHERE app_bar_id_309f86af IS NOT NULL;
```

(Note this is a dramatization, the real database isn't *this* bad.)

Ideally, I'd like to be able to write something in a similar vein to this:

```sql
INSERT INTO {{App.foo}}
SELECT DISTINCT
    {{bar.id}} AS {{foo.id}},
    {{bar.name}} AS {{foo.name}}
FROM {{App.bar}}
WHERE {{bar.id}} IS NOT NULL;
```

and then have the actual field names automatically filled in. I could possibly roll my own with `str.format` or something, but this seems like the sort of thing that should already have a solution.

How can I write raw SQL queries that don't require hardcoding the database table and field names for the models in question?

Comment: One possibility is to generate a table model on the spot and use that. Haven't done that using Django though so can't confirm that works.

Comment: I'm not clear why the queries you have given here need to be written as raw SQL. As I'm sure you know, one good way of avoiding hard-coding table names is to use Django's ORM. Why isn't that an option?

Comment: @Chris The queries here might be doable with Django ORM, but there are other queries that are not, are more complicated/difficult to understand in Django, or have other issues like race conditions or unacceptably low performance.

Comment: Can you explain reason why you should use query like that with your situation in more detail? I am intriguing what your intention to use like that. Did you restrict your situation as 'only your name of field change'? Is it available that new field could be added or deleted?